# Error installing Knex with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, knex.js

Have this error message when installing Knex using npm install knex --save on the command line.  Has anybody run into this problem before or have suggested solutions.

[image: command line snip]

Comment: could you check your package.json to see knex dependency?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-hbs": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "hbs": "^4.0.0",
    "hbsfy": "^2.7.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "knex": "^0.12.6",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "moment-countdown": "0.0.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",    "nodemon": "^1.9.2"

    "pg": "^4.5.6",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "superagent": "^1.8.3",
    "superagent-promise": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },

Comment: Looks like it was installed without errors. Those are just warnings which you can ignore (because you can't do anything about them).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't specify --save 
npm by default saves it as dependence and not dev-dependence